# caching controller action if thread is changing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

If localization of the website is done in such a way that on every request in mvc controller I read current thread and upon that information partial view is loaded (cause every language has different partial view) and strings inside non partial view are localized using resource strings.

Controller using data annotation to set Localize custom attribute

```
[Localize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string partialView = string.Empty;
        switch (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString())
        {
            case "en-US":
            partialView = "english";
            ....
        }
        ViewBag.PartialViewName = partialView;
        return View();
    }
}
```

> my question is: how can I cache this `Index` action knowing that there
>   is 7 different languages?

Update:
If I use for example

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 300)]
public ActionResult Index()
{}
```

then I'm losing switching language ability.

Comment: How are you caching otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just cache by a custom parameter

```
 [OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByCustom = "CurCulture")]
```

In your projects global.asax.cs add the following:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg) 
{ 
    if (arg.Equals("CurCulture")) 
    {
        var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
        return culture;
    }

    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg); 
}
```

Now your outputcache is caching your views based upon the users current ui-culture.

If you have multiple VaryByCustom attributes across your controllers, you need to enhance that method with the aditional logic.

Reference: **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ecf4420.aspx**

Answer (score 1):

Use VaryByCustom property in OutputCache attribute

```
[OutputCache(VaryByCustom = "CultureCode")]
```

Also you can override GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom) in HttpApplication class(so in your Global.asax.cs file) and add logic that will return your current culture